# how to Upload a files from Desktop to Azure blob storage using azure Function app

Tags: python, azure, file-upload, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to Upload some files form my PC through a azure function app. At first i read some excel files then i do some Cleaning processes using Pandas and i want to upload it to Azure function app. offline every works fine, but as i published to Azure it gives *Error 500*.
I'm guessing it can't get files from my PC.

my code looks like this:

```
#I get my files offline
AISauftragID = req.params.get('ID','756382')
Position = req.params.get('Position','7')
location = fr'C:\Users\bb\ff\Doc\VS Code\{ID}-{Position}'
#Some Cleaning using pandas
#connecting to Azure
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("blablabla")
# Instantiate a new ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('foldername')
try:
    # Create new Container in the service
    container_client.create_container()
    properties = container_client.get_container_properties()
except ResourceExistsError:
    print("Container already exists.")
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="blablabla",
                                                container_name="foldername",
                                                blob_name="filename") 
if blob.exists():
        logging.info('filename.csv exists')  
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "filename.csv exists",
            status_code=200)
        
else:
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("filename.csv")
    # upload data
    blob_client.upload_blob(dataframe.to_csv(index=False, encoding = "utf-8"), blob_type="BlockBlob")
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "Konto.csv exists",
            status_code=200)
```

my function.Json file looks like this:

```
    {
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
   
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this work? [Connect Azure Function to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-web-app/azure-function-file-upload#:~:text=Open%20the%20./local.settings.json%20file%20and%20replace%20the%20AzureWebJobsStorage%20property%27s%20value%20with%20UseDevelopmentStorage%3Dtrue%20to%20ensure%20that%20when%20you%20develop%20locally%2C%20the%20function%20uses%20the%20local%20Azurite%20storage%20emulator%3A)

Comment: [Azure Blob storage output binding for Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python),  [How to specify a VS Code binding to upload a file from /tmp to blob storage in an Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379974/how-to-specify-a-vs-code-binding-to-upload-a-file-from-tmp-to-blob-storage-in-a) and [How to Upload Files to Azure Storage Blobs Using Python](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/azure/how-to-upload-files-to-azure-storage-blobs-using-python.html)

Comment: [Upload image to azure blob storage using python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70166175/15969115), [How to Upload and Download Blobs from Azure Blob Storage Using Python](https://medium.com/@cndro/how-to-upload-and-download-blobs-from-azure-blob-storage-using-python-6e5306aa7089) and [azure-sdk-for-python-storage-blob-upload-download-example.py](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-python-storage-blob-upload-download/blob/1bcb2e4d5dd0c41f11889621bda55c0ce4cf1f16/example.py)

Comment: If the configuration is correct, then follow these references to resolve 500 error: [Azure Function Read & Write to Blobs Storage throwing internal 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769200/azure-function-read-write-to-blobs-storage-throwing-internal-500-error) and [Azure Function - HTTP response code 500 Internal Server Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/515190/azure-function-http-response-code-500-internal-ser.html)

Comment: [Blob Storage: connection to emulator, local development fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437824/blob-storage-connection-to-emulator-local-development-fail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm guessing it can't get files from my PC.

That is correct. The azure function runs somewhere in an Azure Cloud data center. There is no way this function can access the local harddrive of an on-premises workstation. Also, you really don't want to because it would be a major security risk.

You seem to have the idea to use an azure function for uploading the local file, as stated, that is a no go. You need some client process like a browser or application to send the file to azure and then you can write an azure function or whatever to process that file.

To process a file you either create an http triggered azure function that accepts a POST action with the file content or [you upload the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=environment-variable-windows#upload-blobs-to-a-container) to, for example, azure blob storage and create a [blob triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) / [event grid triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-python) azure function to process the file.